# What are those aircraft flying over my house?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I took pictures of 6 aircraft at Long Beach, California. Although I see them a lot of times, I have yet to hear the name.

These photos were taken on August 6, 2020:
[image]
A blue and orange biplane on 5:34 PM.

[image]
A gray, long-winged aircraft on 6:02 PM.

And these photos were taken on August 7, 2020:
[image]

A two-bladed rotor blue helicopter on 6:23 PM.

[image]

A white, mid-winged aircraft on 7:01 PM.

[image]

A white, high-winged aircraft on 7:04 PM.

[image]

A black, mid-winged aircraft on 7:19 PM.

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: Rather than posting fuzzy pictures here in the hope that someone can identify them, get yourself a reasonable pair of binoculars (10x50 should give good results) and read the registration (the N-number) from under the wing or the fuselage side. You can look those numbers up on the [FAA registry](https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/). If you find reading those numbers off the aircraft in flight too difficult, head to the airport and do it there. With binoculars and a smartphone you could teach yourself a lot about aircraft recognition in just a couple of hours.

Comment: I don't think I am good at asking questions in here; they keep getting downvotes.

Comment: @KyleCocjin people have explained to you why these questions got downvoted. it is up to you how to best use this information.

Comment: Most likely this question is gonna close after the bounty because of the downvotes.

Comment: @KyleCocjin given your questions, I think you should meet some spotters. A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=avgeek+spotters+long+beach+california&tbm=isch) points to several pinterest, twitter and facebook accounts.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be closed? It has 4 downvotes.

Answer (score 10):

Two things:

1. The helicopter is a Robinson R-44.
2. This is the fourth time you have come on this site to ask the posters to identify aircraft flying out of your local airfield. Do yourself a favor. Go down to your local airfield and become a fixture. You will learn a lot more about the aircraft you are inquiring about from the actual people who fly and maintain them. Most pilots and mechanics are more than happy to share their passion for aviation. Heck! Some of them may even offer you a ride. Then, if you have questions about specific aviation subjects after you have researched them, come to this site and ask. More than likely, you will get the answers from the horses’ mouths at the airfield even before you ask them.

Comment: Okay. Someday, I will make another question that may be different. It won’t be aircraft identification on there.

Comment: @Kyle Cocjin, I actually laughed out loud after reading Dean's answer then checking your profile!  Good on you for your enthusiasm, but I agree with Dean.  And i think you will get more out of researching aircraft types ahead of time, then trying to ID them yourself rather than just asking others.  But don't be afraid to ask if you get stuck on a tough one, maybe just not every airplane you see...

Comment: Okay, I should do this from now on.

Comment: +1, mainly for the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Photo 1: Not totally clear but appears to be a Boeing Stearman

Photo 2: Unknown

Photo 3: Robinson R66 with camera pod, most likely a news or police helicopter.

Photo 4: Unknown. Possibly a Cirrus SR-2X series.

Photo 5: Either a Cessna 172RG or 182RG

Photo 6: Piper PA-28 Cherokee

Answer (score 1):

1: Boeing Stearman

2: Unknown but possibly part of the Cessna company

3: Robinson R44 or R66

4: Most likely a Cirrus SR-2X

5: Cessna 172RG or 182RG

6: Likely a PA-28 Cherokee

Answer (score 0):

For future use - there is app that you can run on your phone. Point it at a plane that you see and it will tell you info about the plane. Type w pic, tail number, to, from, speed, height, etc.  It won’t work for every plane, but it works for most. The app is called FlightAware and the function is the AR button. I think the free version has the AR. I think the paid version also displays the FAA registered owner.